# phpMyAdmin event error #1542 interval too big

Tags: mysql, events

I have an MySQL event that deletes any rows older than 1 month. I now want to change that so it deletes rows older than 6 months (it cleans up a database for messages sent in a game).

My (edited) MySQL event is:

```
DELETE FROM messages WHERE date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

The error I get is:

```
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` EVENT `delete msgs` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 0 DAY_HOUR STARTS '2013-07-19 18:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO DELETE FROM messages WHERE date &lt; (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)"
MySQL said: #1542 - INTERVAL is either not positive or too big
```

The event functions fine but I can't even save it as it is now. If I open the event and immediately save I get the same error.

Comment: `EVERY 0 DAY_HOUR` is not fine I guess. How often should the event run?

Comment: It should execute every 10 hours. I currently have Execute every '0 10' DAY_HOUR entered in the field. Did the syntax change or something?

Comment: That was it, I have no idea why it worked before. It accepted the query after changing the execture every field :) I now just set it to Execute every: 10 HOUR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juergen d basically answered my question in a comment. The interval was set to "EVERY 0 DAY_HOUR" while in phpmyadmin it was set to "EVERY '0_10' DAY_HOUR". I was able to save it before with the '0_10' but apparently that doesn't work anymore, or maybe never worked (even though the event did it's thing).

I changed that to "EVERY 10 HOUR" and now it saves fine.